# JS manipulation on CSS and how it result on page rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know from many sources that applying CSS ***after*** the page has loaded can cause "flashing" effect - means the page will re-render the CSS.

For example:

```
<head></head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet"... />
</body>
```

However, I can't find any source for applying CSS(***not inline***) with JS after the page is loaded and how it's reflected by the re-rendering it self.

For example:

HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="divid" class="displaynone"></div>
<script>
function showit(){
document.getElementById("divid").className += " displayblock";}
window.onload = showit;
</script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.displaynone {display:none;}
.displayblock {display:block;}
```

Will the second example will be forced to re-render the css after the page is loaded? I want to understand the deeps of how the `displayblock` is actually apply to the `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply your `<link rel="stylesheet"... />` after your DOM elements in your markup you can end up with "flickering" effects. This is caused because when the browser load the CSS file (a network request is made), the DOM is being already displayed in the ViewPort (which has not yet any style applied).

In the second case where you add `<link rel="stylesheet"... />` in your head, the browser download your CSS file before rendering the DOM on the ViewPort. At this point your JavaScript change class attribute to the DOM and you have no flickering (as all CSS has been already loaded).

When you change the DOM with a property which is related to the its visual representation the browser execute a "paint" this means that an area of the ViewPort is  partially or fully re-rendered.

An interesting article regarding browser [painting and performance](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/unnecessary-paints/) and [rendering path](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/analyzing-crp). Also of interest if you are using [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/analyze-runtime?hl=en).

Comment: A little offtopic and probably a little SO quirk, but when clicking on any text within this answer the whole paragraph fades in and then out. http://i.imgur.com/5NC8jTP.gifv - Edit: fixed after the answer was accepted or edited.

Comment: Thank you, I just thought the same thing while googling and trying understand why is it "flashing"(in first example) from the begging.

Comment: So it actually do re-render it self anyway? But in the second example it will re-render only the div(and what it contains)?

Comment: OMG! Thanks for the "painting and performance" link... I couldn't even think it will re-paint when scrolling. Kinda shocking :)

Comment: @greenh In the second example, usually a partial paint (rendering) is performed. Partial or full painting depending of which property you are editing.

Comment: @greenh you can analyse performance regarding painting activity and other parameters using Chome Dev Tolls, I have edited my question with a link. :)

Comment: Thanks once again, buddy!